# Yii disable Model Behavior for one Controller

Tags: php, yii

Im using a behavior(DateTimeI18NBehavior) in Users.php model, but specifically in a controller (ApiController.php) I would like to disable it.

---

Model - Users.php:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return array(
        'datetimeI18NBehavior'=>array(
            'class' => 'ext.DateTimeI18NBehavior',
        ),
    );
}
```

---

I know that I can it disable with:

```
$model->disableBehavior('datetimeI18NBehavior');
```

But how to disable to entire Controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure, but maybe this would work:

```
class ApiController extends CController
{
    function init()
    {
        Users::model()->disableBehavior('datetimeI18NBehavior');
    }
}
```

Or you can try to add some logic in your model:

```
function behaviors()
{
    if (Yii::app()->controller->uniqueId != 'api') {
        return parent::behaviors();
    }
    return array(
        'datetimeI18NBehavior'=>array(
            'class' => 'ext.DateTimeI18NBehavior',
        ),
    );
}
```

Both ways aren't perfect though in my opinion.