# Is it possible to cancel function override in parent class and use function from top level parent

Tags: php, oop, yii, polymorphism, encapsulation

```
class TopParent
{
    protected function foo()
    {
        $this->bar();
    }

    private function bar()
    {
       echo 'Bar';
    }
}

class MidParent extends TopParent
{
    protected function foo()
    {
        $this->midMethod();
        parent::foo();
    }

    public function midMethod()
    {
        echo 'Mid';
    }

    public function generalMethod()
    {
       echo 'General';
    }
}
```

Now the question is if I have a class, that extends MidParent because I need to call

```
class Target extends MidParent
{
    //How to override this method to return TopParent::foo(); ?
    protected function foo()
    {
    }
}
```

So I need to do this:

```
$mid = new MidParent();
$mid->foo(); // MidBar
$taget = new Target();
$target->generalMethod(); // General
$target->foo(); // Bar
```

**UPDATE**
Top parent is ActiveRecord class, mid is my model object. I want to use model in yii ConsoleApplication. I use 'user' module in this model, and console app doesn't support this module. So I need to override method afterFind, where user module is called. So the Target class is the class that overrides some methods from model which uses some modules that console application doesn't support.

Comment: One question: why do this?

Comment: In short: no. Clean up what your code does and when it does it if you don't want it to do it.

Comment: Make Target::foo call TopParent::bar ?

Comment: The fact that you think you need to do this demonstrates a failure to grasp the concepts of OOP. This is a huge code smell, I think the best thing you can do is to look at your design again and refactor.

Comment: Re "why update": It's a terrible code smell if "a console app doesn't support something in the model so you need to change the model". Those two things should be completely separate. The model always works the same way, the *View* displays what it can of it.

Comment: User model handles session, but console app doesn't have sessions =)
In my models I can check whether user is guest, or not and then load different rules,relations,scenarios,scopes. It is very comfortably
and easy to use all this stuff. And I just added a class with just several overrides, and cosole app works great. where is the smell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly - you can't. This is how OOP works.

You can do it by a little redesign, e.g. in MidParent add method:

```
protected function parentFoo()
{
    parent::foo();
}
```

and in Target:

```
public function foo()
{
    $this->parentFoo();
}
```

But, again, this is only a workaround to solve your question and not a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php - not allow to overriding in the childrens):

> ```
> final protected function foo()
> {
>     $this->midMethod();
>     parent::foo();
> }
> ```

in class `MidParent` and the class `Target` can't overrides this method.

Comment: I need to override in Target, but I also need to use TopParent foo() in Target

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you *can do this* like this way with [Reflection::getParentClass()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getparentclass.php):

```
class Foo
{
   public function test($x, $y)
   {
      echo(sprintf('I am test of Foo with %s, %s'.PHP_EOL, $x, $y));
   }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
   public function test()
   {
      echo('I am test of Bar'.PHP_EOL);
      parent::test();
   }
}

class Baz extends Bar
{
   public function test()
   {
      $class = new ReflectionClass(get_class($this));
      return call_user_func_array(
         [$class->getParentClass()->getParentClass()->getName(), 'test'],
         func_get_args()
      );
   }
}

$obj = new Baz();
$obj->test('bee', 'feo'); //I am test of Foo with bee, feo
```

-but this is an architecture smell in any case. If you need something like this, that should tell you: you're doing something wrong. I don't want to recommend anyone to use this way, but since it's possible - here it is.

Answer (score 0):

@AnatoliyGusarov, your question is interesting and in a sense you can achieve what you desire using yii and php advances features like [Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) and [Traits in Yii](http://www.peterspain.co.uk/2012/03/15/php-5-4-traits-in-yii/).

Given that it depends on what version of php you are using.However in yii you can achieve this by [behaviors](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/44/behaviors-events/) and check this [SOQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997076/yii-disable-model-behavior-for-one-controller).

In a nutshell you have to use language advanced features or YII framework features to come around this kind of issues,but that boils down to actual requirements